# Create link with asciidoctor that has an ID

Tags: asciidoctor

I would like to create a external link with an ID using asciidoctorj. I couldn't find anywhere in the manual a way on how to do it.

Asciidoctor Source:

```
http://stackoverflow.com[Cool Site, id="myId"] ...
```

Current result:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Cool Site</a> ...
```

Expected result:

```
<a id="myId" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Cool Site</a> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible (for now): http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#links

But you can define `role` to produce HTML class, for example:

```
http://discuss.asciidoctor.org[Discuss Asciidoctor, role="external"]
```

will produce:

```
<a href="http://discuss.asciidoctor.org" class="external">Discuss Asciidoctor</a>
```

You can also open an issue [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues) to ask for it!

Comment: Apparently you already have https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/935

Comment: I am waiting for https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/pull/966 to become a release. As this contains the ideal solution.